# How to resize (stretch) Android RatingBar without adding more Stars

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to resize an Android RatingBar.
When I specify larger size for the RatingBar in my XML-Layout, it just gets stretched showing more Stars.

Answer (score 1):

set your ratingbar's width to WRAP_CONTENT

Answer (score 0):

Use [`android:numStars`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#attr_android:numStars)?

Comment: That's what I did. I set android:numStars="5" (default) and also set android:layout_width="fill_parent". Which is showing me a lot more than 5 Stars (I guess about 12 on my Nexus).
When I select the 12th star the number returned by ratingbar.getNumStars() is 5.